# Is jQuery append method creates the DOM based XSS attack?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some confusion. I need to sure that is jQuery's append method` create the DOM-based XSS attack. I am providing my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="form-control" id="cmbEnrollProcess" name="cmbEnrollProcess"></select>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="xssecho();">Add</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function xssecho(){
            var options = "<option value=''>Select Enrollment Process</option>";
            console.log('option',options);
            $('#cmbEnrollProcess').html("");   
            $('#cmbEnrollProcess').append(options);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am adding the option value dynamically using jQuery's append method. I need to find out whether this method create the DOM based XSS attack or not ?

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking_.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking... but adding element with strings can open up for attacks... Example:

```js
var value = "'><script>console.log(`dang`)</sc"+"ript><option>"
var options = "<option value='"+value+"'>Select Enrollment Process</option>";
$('select').append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

one way to be safe is creating the value like this with jQuery:

```
var options = $('<option>', {
  text: 'Select Enrollment Process',
  value: 'few'
})
$('select').append(options)
```